# get jquery .load() to append rather than replace?

Tags: jquery

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery.get() to append data...

```
jQuery.get("URL", function(data) {
    jQuery("#myElement").append(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to use `.get`:

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').append(data);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/